# Why the Spectral Theorem does not exist in a Euclidean Space when proving

Tags: linear-algebra

When I read ***Algebra by Artin***, I am confused why the proof can not be generalized to the Euclidean Space.(Since the fact that some orthogonal operator can not be diagbosed)
This is the proof:(In the picture)I can not find which point is broken in a Euclidean space.

[image]

Comment: When you write "Euclidean Space" are you thinking of $\Bbb{R}^n$ or $\Bbb{C}^n$?

Comment: I mean $\Bbb{R}^n$

Comment: Over $\mathbb{R}$, there need not be an eigenvector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the linear operator $T = \begin{pmatrix}  3 & -2 \\ 4 & -1\end{pmatrix}$ acting on $\Bbb{R}^2$.  This has nonreal eigenvalues $1 \pm 2\mathrm{i}$ with eigenvectors $\begin{pmatrix}1+\mathrm{i} \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1-\mathrm{i} \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$, neither of which is a vector in $\Bbb{R}^2$.  Consequently, no choice of $v_1$ in the proof yields a basis for $\Bbb{R}^2$.

(More generally, a real matrix need not have real eigenvalues, which is the window through which nonreal eigenvectors enter.)

The example above is dissected in some detail at [http://www.math.utk.edu/~freire/complex-eig2005.pdf](http://www.math.utk.edu/%7Efreire/complex-eig2005.pdf) .